# Restlet, HTTPS and Swagger

Tags: restlet, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Restlet to generate JSON for Swagger 2.0. I'm requiring that my /api URI be served over HTTPS only. When looking at the JSON returned, nothing is specified about the protocol and subsequently Swagger-UI attempts to use HTTP even though I requested the JSON over HTTPS.

Is there anything I can do so that the "Try It Out!" functions will perform the requests over HTTPS only?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the introspection tool, you can add the "--endpoint" parameter. It helps to specify the endpoint and specify the supported schemes

e.g.:
--endpoint https://example.com

If you are not using the introspection tool, could you give more details?